# Two class inheriting one abstract class

Tags: c#, abstract

How do I define the abstract method if class Example1 and class Example 2 have subscribe method that pass in different parameter?

```
abstract class Test
{
public int _a;
public abstract void Subscribe();
}

class Example1 : Test
{
    public override void Subscribe(int x,int y,int z)
    {
    }
}

class Example2 : Test
{
    public override void Subscribe(string a, bool b)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work? You need to pass those parameters in code later. You cannot pass a dynamic number of parameters into a function.

Comment: @Neolisk You can use `params`.

Comment: `Example2` doesn't have a `subscribe` method, it has an `A` method

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Asad: Yeah, I guess, but I don't like this approach. It does not scale well. :)

Comment: If `Example1` and `Example2` need particular definitions of `Subscribe()` and aren't sharing those definitions, then `Test` can't represent them both.

Comment: If you want two methods with different parameters then you should really **revisit your reason to inherit from an abstract class** in first place.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a single parameter of type A, then work with types B and C in classes Example1 and Example2, both of which would inherit from A. You would still have A in the method signature though, but able to squeeze some additional logic in descendants.

Comment: I am trying to do something like if (true) Test abc=new Example1() and if (false) Test abc=new Example2(); and then in my code, I can use abc.Subscribe() throughout my code

Comment: Then, what you need to do is define a Subscribe() method, and pass x,y,z or a,b to the constructor of Example1 and Example2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy.  Just take the `Subscribe` method out of `Test`

```
abstract class Test
{
    public int _a;
}
```

---

Those subscribe methods are different methods.  You need to think of them in the same way as you would think of methods with different names, even if they serve a similar purpose.

If they're unique to their derived class, than there's no reason why you need them in the base method in the first place.

---

If you need to determine which `Subscribe` to call on your `Test` at runtime, than you can use `is`

```
if(abc is Example1)
{
    ((Example1)abc).Subscribe(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like if (true) Test abc=new Example1() and if (false) Test abc=new Example2(); and then in my code, I can use abc.Subscribe

Comment: @user3398315 but after you've instanciated `abc`, how do you intend to decide whether or not to call `Subscribe`?

Comment: I will need to call Subscribe. User input will determine whether to call it with Example 1 or Example 2.

Comment: `instanceOf` is not a C# operator.

Comment: @Kyle  wow, normally it's the other way around and I end up writing `c#` answers to java questions

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to ensure merely that the derived classes *have* a `Subscribe` method, and that it can take some arbitrary number of arguments, you can use this:

```
abstract class Test {
    public abstract void Subscribe(params object[] args);
}
```

You can then implement the `Subscribe` method in your derived classes, but you must use the `params` signature, which makes no compile time guarantee you'll be getting arguments of the correct type or quantity:

```
class Example1 : Test
{

    public override void Subscribe(params object[] abcd)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;

        if (abcd[0] is int)
            x = (int) abcd[0];
        else
            // Complain about this
            throw new ArgumentException("The first argument is not an integer");

        // Check for other parameters
        // ...

        Example1Subscribe(x, y, z);
    }

    public void Example1Subscribe(int x, int y, int z)
    {

    }
}
```